# How to handle concating strings if one of the strings is null?

Tags: dart

The String `path1` is derived from concatenating two strings. One string is hardcoded and the other string might be null. If the `id` string is null, I'd like path1 to be null. I'm thinking of doing a try/catch on `electorates.legislatures[lt.type].id`. Just wondering is there an elegant way to do this in line?

`path1 = '/legislatures/' + electorates.legislatures[lt.type].id`,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want the resulting string to be `null`, you could do:

```dart
var concatenation = suffix?.replaceRange(0, 0, prefix);
```

which in your case would be:

```dart
path1 = electorates.legislatures[lt.type].id?.replaceRange(0, 0, '/legislatures/');
```

(If *eliminating* `null` values could be an option instead of *propagating* them, a typical approach would be to do `var concatenation = prefix ?? '' + suffix ?? '';`.)

Comment: I must say that if I saw this code in a pull request it would be rejected because of nearly none readability since it is hard to look at the code and fully understand the consequences. But cool solution regardless. :)

Answer (score 2):

You could make an extension method like this which add a method there does what you want on the `String` object:

```
void main() {
  print('test'.concatOrNull(null)); // null
  print('test'.concatOrNull('123')); // test123
}

extension concatOrNullExtension on String {
  String concatOrNull(String other) => other == null ? null : this + other;
}
```